# Hot to create a 'no http response' alarm in AWS CloudWatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm using Amazon CloudWatch in order to configure some alarms on my EC2 Intance.

My main concern is the system downtime. I configure a Status Check for the server. However it seems that the 'status check' only checks if the server is on and operating. What I really need to know if the server is able to reply http request, not just if it's on or not.

How can I configure an alarm in cloudwatch to check status of the system using this parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Its a 2 step process. It requires an ALB/ELB setup. Those check a static page for a health check. We use a simple static page so its very little overhead. If a server fails a health check, it falls out of the ALB/ELB until it becomes healthy again.

Cloudwatch can monitor the count of how many healthy/unhealthy hosts are in the ALB/ELBs. We set alerts for that.